# Code completion for html files

Tags: html, dart

I worked a lot with Flex and now want to migrate to Dart.
One of the superb features in Flex are its code completion features, for both the action script and markup.
Is there an editor out there that has the same code completion features while editing Dart html files. So for example while type 'core' it show a list of all html tags starting with core. And after selecting say core-animated-pages if shows a list all possible attributes etc.

Txs in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). You can view Live Preview and its Code completion property is awesome.

Comment: or any other IDE with Dart and HTML support (WebStorm, Eclipse, Sublime Text, VIM, ...) DartEditor is a good entry level IDE. It's tailored to Dart which makes it very easy to start Dart development. If you need more features other IDEs might be a better fit.